# Why do I get ORA-20000 when I run dbms_stats.gather_table_stats on a table in SSB Schema?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I wanted to generate some CPU load on my ADB-S database. I tried to collect the optimizer statistics on a table from the sample schema SSB, but I got this error, even if I am connected as ADMIN user:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SSB','CUSTOMER');
BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SSB','CUSTOMER'); END;
Error report -
ORA-20000: Unable to analyze TABLE "SSB"."CUSTOMER", insufficient privileges or does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40921
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40193
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40352
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40902
ORA-06512: at line 1
20000. 00000 - "%s"
*Cause: The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action: Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
the application administrator or DBA for more information.
```

Answer (score 2):

Not being able to change anything on SSB (or any sample schema for that matter) is intentional. Those are purely read-only schemas and the stats on them are controlled by Oracle.

Oracle documentation mentions that sample schemas are read-only:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/autonomous-sample-data.html#GUID-4BB2B49B-0C20-4E38-BCC7-A61D3F45390B